# Undefined method in ActiveSupport concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport, activesupport-concern

I have a model that extends `ActiveRecord::Base` and includes a concern:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include UserConcern

    def self.create_user()
        ...
        results = some_method()
    end

end
```

`UserConcern` is stored in the `concerns` directory:

```
module UserConcern
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def some_method()
        ...
    end
end
```

I am getting a run-time error when I try to create a new user by calling the `create_user` method that looks like this:

```
undefined method 'some_method' for #<Class:0x000000...>
```

I have two questions about this:

1. Why is the `some_method` undefined? It seems to me that I am properly including it with the statement `include UserConcern`. Does it have something to do with my `User` class extending `ActiveRecord::Base`? Or maybe something to do with the fact that I am calling `some_methods()` from a class method (i.e. `self.create_user()`)?
2. Why does the run-time error refer to `#<Class:0x000000...>` instead of to `#<User:0x000000...>`?

Comment: Indeed the error is because you are trying to call an instance method inside a class method. And the runtime error refers to `#<Class` because the class  `User` is an instance of the class `Class`.

Comment: Either your `some_method` depends on an instance or not, if it doesn't make it a class method and everything should work as you expect. If it does, then you need to rethink why you are calling it inside a class method. Maybe you expect an instance as an argument?

Comment: And finally, if in fact your method `create_user` does what it name indicates then you probably take a look at the before and after create callbacks to do something when a new instance is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

models/concerns/user_concern.rb:

```
module UserConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def some_instance_method
    'some_instance_method'
  end

  included do
    def self.some_class_method
      'some_class_method'
    end
  end
end
```

models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UserConcern
  def self.create_user
    self.some_class_method
  end
end
```

rails console:

```
user = User.new
user.some_instance_method
# => "some_instance_method"

User.some_class_method
# => "some_class_method"

User.create_user
# => "some_class_method"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: This worked for me, except I placed `some_class_method` into a `module ClassMethods...end` block and without the `self` reference.